# Perl SpreadSheet::XLSX Error: "Cannot open as Zip Archive"

Tags: excel, perl, spreadsheet

I'm trying to use [`Spreadsheet:XLSX`](http://metacpan.org/module/Spreadsheet:XLSX) to read Excel files, but I get this error message with CSV, XLS, and XLSX file uploads. I had it working previously with [`Spreadsheet::Read`](http://metacpan.org/module/Spreadsheet::Read) and CSV files.

The code is so simple I just don't know what to troubleshoot.

The file uploads correctly and I have the correct path and filename.

Error message:

```
Cannot open c:\Website\cgi-bin\bidprocess\files\SEIPA-request-0307123509.xlsx as Zip archive at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/Spreadsheet/XLSX.pm line 279.
```

Code:

```
# CHECK FOR VALID FILE 
my $filename = shift or die "ERROR: File not received.  Please try again.";

#DEBUG
print $filename;

# READ EXCEL FILE 
my $workbook = Spreadsheet::XLSX->new($filename);
```

Comment: Not sure why it would work with CSV or XLS files: neither of these is stored in a zip format...

Comment: Also - check the xlsx file you're having a problem with to make sure it's the correct format.  Change the extension to "zip" and try to open it and view the contents.

Comment: How do you know *"The file uploads correctly"*? Have you tried to open it with Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that took forever for such a simple thing.

The solution was to open the file in "binary mode" because I'm using Windows which differentiates between text and binary data.

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html

```
use CGI qw(:standard);

# upload file
my $upload_filehandle = upload("filename"); 

# open the uploaded file
open ( UPLOADFILE, ">$upload_dir/$filename" ) or die "$!";

# use binary mode (for Excel files on Windows)
binmode UPLOADFILE;
```

Comment: Your solution needs more information before it can be useful to others. You didn't show any code that opens your uploaded file. Is that in the code that uploads the file, or where it is read on the server? It isn't Windows but Perl whose behaviour is different. Windows terminates each line of a text file with CR LF, whereas Linux uses just CR. The default for Perl on a Windows system is to remove the CR, but that is clearly bad news for a zip file where 0x0D (CR) may just be part of the data

Comment: I honestly couldn't find any real documentation or examples about it except that link I posted.  I don't pretend to be a cross-platform raw data expert. :)  I can only imagine that this is relatively unknown because Perl websites are typically run on Linux.

Comment: Thanks for updating your solution, but the sort of information I would like is what I'm certain that you do know. For instance, which library provides the `upload` function, and is this code server side or client side?

Answer (score 0):

You can't open CSV or XLS files with [Spreadsheet:XLSX](http://metacpan.org/module/Spreadsheet:XLSX). As the name implies, it's for XLSX files which are zipped XML files. If it won't open these then your file is probably corrupt

Comment: It works for all of them if you use [Spreadsheet::Read.](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Spreadsheet-Read/Read.pm)

Comment: @ColeTarbet: Then my best guess is that your XLSX file is really something else. Can you put it online so that I can test with it?

Answer (score -1):

Since it appears that you are on Windows, one option open to you if you have Excel installed on that system is to use the [Win32::OLE](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::OLE) module to directly control Excel to read/write Excel files.

For CSV files, it may be easier to directly parse the contents as if it was a text file or use something like the [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) module.